# Запуск программы на Java под Windows

Tags: java, компиляция

Простой вопрос, который поставил меня в тупик.

Есть небольшое приложение , которое просто считает введеные в консоль числа и выводит их сумму.

Задание - запуск полученной программы с компьютера, например под windows в формате .exe , но  на нем не установлена java. Это реально? Гуглил что есть программы-обертки которые могут cкомпилировать программу в exe файл, но при этом все равно требуется установленая java.

Comment: Нужно скачать Java JRE с официального сайта Oracle, установить и запустить ваше приложение. Собственно, все...

Answer (score 3):

Действительно, есть, например, программа Launch4j (http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/), с помощью которой можно "обернуть" Вашу программу.

Конечно, без JRE программу на Java запустить в общем случае не получится, но в Launch4j, насколько мне известно, есть возможность встроить JRE в .exe:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49553161